# How to have a cell calculate only once

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba

I have cell `N29` calculating some values based on streaming data. Once a condition is met in cell `Q29`, the calculation or final value should be passed to cell `O29` and no longer calculate in either cell.

For example: If cell `Q29` = *y* then `O29` should equal the last calculation of `N29` (and no longer calculate) and `N29` should be set to 0 and no longer calculate.

Comment: Are you open to VBA solutions?

Comment: Yes if need be. Anything is greatly appreaciated.

Comment: is there a formula in Q29? If so, does it have to stay a formula, once it reaches 'y'? You might want to move all of the calculation in N29 into a macro and skip testing with Q29 completely, but that means knowing more about your calculation. If you are refreshing data regularly the cell value change event is not possible, but a time delay check can work

Comment: No Q29 doesn't have a formula. Here is what i have: Cell Q29 can either be yes or no. the yes or no will determine the value of N29=IF(OR(AND(G29="s",G32="b",Q29="y",Q32="y"),AND(G29="b",G32="s",Q29="y",Q32="y")),0,((L29*M29)-(I29*M29))/L29) ----and here is the formula for the other cell 0  =IF(N29=0,((L29*M29)-(I29*M29))/L32+((L32*M32)-(I32*M32))/L32) --- I agree that the calculations can be moved to a macro. but how? Thanks!

Comment: so are any of these data entries, or are they all streaming, and the calculation triggers on the refresh now?

Comment: a number of things are still not clear to me. Is O29 empty to start, and how is Q29 getting a "y" entry if it is not a formula?

Comment: here to clarify. Cell O29 is calculating realtime profit and loss while a position is open, all calculated on row 29. Once the position is closed on row 32, Cell Q32=Y, (Has no formula but other cells reference cell Q looking to see if it's Y or not.. Cell O32 amd Cell O29 should equal to 0 and the profit and loss should only calculate once in cell O32. Hope this helps.. thank you all in advance

Comment: if this is a template, and there is a formula in O29, can we merely check if O32 is 'Y' and if there is a formula in O29. If so change the formula to the fixed value, and perhaps format the color to show you, that O32 no longer is changing O29. would that work? or do you need to be able to reset this same sheet again?

Comment: O29 does have a formula. We'd be checking to see if Q32 = Y. O32 is running a calculation as well. SO in words. If Q29 = y and Q32=N then N29 continue calculating realtime; O29 and O32 = 0.. If Q29 and Q32 both = Y then N29=0, O29=N29 last Value, O32= N29 last value (or last calculation).

Comment: @Marco, please, edit the Q to include all yours comments.

Answer (score 0):

Include the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Q29 As Range
    Set Q29 = Range("Q29")
    If Intersect(Target, Q29) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Q29 <> "y" Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("O29").Value = Range("N29").Value
        Range("N29").Value = 0
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

macros must be enabled for this to work!